# How can I create Custom register component in nebular theme with NbSelect (multiple)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created custom register page and override constructor.
I have added `NbSelect` on `Register` page but it gives me warning as below:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't assign single value if select is marked as multiple
```

The error occurs while adding attribute `multiple`.

Please help me if anyone has solution for this.

Comment: Can you share some code

Comment: <nb-select [(ngModel)]="user.Connector" #Connector="ngModel" id="input-Connector" name="Connector" placeholder="Select Connector" fullWidth size="large" [status]="Connector.dirty ? (Connector.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : 'basic'"
            [required]="getConfigValue('forms.validation.Connector.required')" [attr.aria-invalid]="Connector.invalid && Connector.touched ? true : null" [(selected)]="user.Connector" [multiple]="true">
            <nb-option *ngFor="let item of connectors" [value]="item.ConnectorId">{{item.ConnectorTitle}}</nb-option>
        </nb-select>

Comment: @MandarChavan - there is an open issue on GitHub for same error for different scenario than yours.   https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1950

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat - Yes I have tried that too but I am using nebular theme. it doesn't accept such thing. I am looking for the solution for Nebular theme specifically. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat when i remove binding and error message then that error gets removed. I think the error is at  **[(ngModel)]="user.Connector"**. it might be binding issue.